# Java duplicating actions

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I would like help with the problem below, if possible:

- I use MySQL as a database, one day I went to do an experiment that ended up generating an error, not in the records, but in the project action itself, what happens is that: Every time I query all the objects in the database to check if there is something in some object and return an "other" below if there is not, if MySQL has in its table two or more objects, it returns several times the same answer that in the case is the number of objects they have in the MySQL table.

Code: [Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjcjE.png)

- Error: If I run this code and I have two or more accounts inside the table I am querying, it will repeat ALL the actions of the "other" according to the number of accounts in the table.

I apologize for my English. :/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please avoid providing images of your code. Instead paste a minimal reproducable code example within your question. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details on how to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood your question correctly, the problem is that you loop through all rows of your table but you only want to operate with 1 row, right?
In MySQL you can use the keyword LIMIT to limit your ResultSet.
So for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable
LIMIT 1;
```

returns the **first row of your Query only.**

If you want distinct ResultSets of your table only you can use they keyword DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnname
FROM testtable;
```

this will return every distinct row one time only.

So let´s say you have a table called animals and in this table you have the column called animalnames with those values: 'Tiger', 'Tiger', 'Elefant'.

```
SELECT animalnames
FROM animals;
```

will return **'Tiger', 'Tiger', 'Elefant'**.

But

```
SELECT DISTINCT animalnames
FROM animals
```

will return **'Tiger', 'Elefant'**.